# Merging 2 excel workbooks

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am writing a python script to copy data from one excel file to another and I have some issues with it.I have 5 columns of data in excel file 1 and data for 6th and 7th column in an another excel file. The requirement is that I would like to paste the data from Excel file 2 in Excel file 1 at columns 6. and 7.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share your existing Code, so others can help you with it and allow them to see, what you tried before.

Comment: Make sure to provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the rows are same in both files. Try this

```
df_1 = pd.read_excel('Excel_1.xls')
df_2 = pd.read_excel('Excel_2.xls')
df_1 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have tried to do it and I have got the exception "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"